# In theory, can a .so file created in one RHEL version be used in any other RHEL version?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library

I have done the compilation of a source package and installed in a custom path, binaries and some shared objects libraries were created and the tool is working.

Can the same installation be used in another RHEL version (at least, can the libraries be used in another RHEL version in theory?)

All I need is at least the libraries should work.

A little explanation would be more helpful.

Comment: Short: if on older versions, then - no. If on newer, then this _may_ work. That's on glibc systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreeing with the comment by [@siblynx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/140866/siblynx), that glibc provides a range of compatibility.  The way it does this (in the range of release for version 6) is using symbol versioning: as each symbol (function or data) is introduced, there is a corresponding *version* attached to the symbol, so that there is a way to link to the proper version automatically.

If the behavior (mainly the binary *interface*) has changed going forward, your application would load using the older versioned interface.  Going backward, the version may not exist, and the application could not load successfully.

At a coarser level, most shared libraries on RHEL also are versioned, but glibc supports the range of compatibility through versions of symbols within a single shared library.

Further reading:

- [ELF Symbol Versioning](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/symbol-versioning) (Ulrich Drepper)
- [The GNU C Library With Versioned Interface](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/libs/glibc/hjl/compat/)
- [Linking to older GLIBC symbols](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2011-04/msg00032.html)
- [How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version)